# Force load mobile Youtube page?

Tags: java, android, youtube, simulator

how can I make a youtube link load in the mobile version? An example is if you load up this link in your browser(http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=06f67ru5tCI) it loads up the mobile version, since "m." is appended to the biginning of the url. This works fine when you load up the link on your normal desktop browser. Whenever I try loading up a mobile link this way on an Android simulator to extract some data from the page it automatically gets redirected to the full "Desktop" version of the link even though "m." was appended to the beginning of the url. How can I force load a mobile Youtube link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way is by changing the user agent. For example:

```
URLConnection con = ...
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1");
```

Comment: This doesent work. Additionally before I tried changing the user-agent the data that was mined from the page was wrong because of being redirected to the desktop version but now after trying this no data is returned and I get this error in Logcat:`W/System.err(1100): java.util.NoSuchElementException` Any ideas?

Comment: So you're saying that after *only* adding the line `con.setRequestProperty(...)` you get an error?

Comment: Yes, that is correct... Any ideas? I literally copy and pasted the code from your example...

Comment: `String fileLocationURLString = "http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=06f67ru5tCI";
     
     URL fileLocationURL = new URL(fileLocationURLString);
     URLConnection mainURLConnection = fileLocationURL
       .openConnection();
     mainURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1");

     mainNode = mainHTMLCleaner.clean(new InputStreamReader(
       mainURLConnection.getInputStream()));
     Object[] linkAddress = mainNode
       .evaluateXPath(LOCATION_XPATH);`

Comment: `if (linkAddress.length > 0) {

      for (int i = 0; i < linkAddress.length; i++) {

       TagNode linkAddressNode = (TagNode) linkAddress[i];
       String info = linkAddressNode.getChildren()
         .iterator().next().toString().trim();
       Log.i("FOUND IT", info);

      }
     }`

Comment: LogCat output: `W/System.err(1207): java.util.NoSuchElementException
W/System.err(1207):  at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:572)
W/System.err(1207):  at com.magnusDevelopment.AdamSmtih.URLFunctions$1.run(URLFunctions.java:85)
`

Comment: Forgive my newbieness but how can you set the request property BEFORE opening a connection?

Comment: Sorry, I had read your code wrong. Can you verify that the you are actually being connected to the mobile site by getting the page source and comparing it with the real mobile page source?

Comment: Already have, I get the desktop page source when I am not change the user agent. But when I change the user-agent an error occurres and nothing is returned.

Comment: No, I mean after you change the user agent. You can do this by simply reading the page to a String.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? The error is saying that the "linkAddress" var is 0 which means that nothing was returned and since it returns fine without the user-agent being changed and the element that I'm mining for exists on both desktop and mobile versions wouldn't that mean that nothing is returned???

Comment: Update: I think I may have figured out the problem. The User-Agent that you provided may have been incorrect becuase I Googled more user-agents and found this one(Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0; xx-xx; Galaxy Nexus Build/ITL41F) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30) that is the user-agent of the galaxy nexus, googles new phone. The program runs fine and returns the page although its still the dekstop version!!! :( Since this was a mobile User-agent maybe changing the user agent isn't helping...